# Make custom shortcut keys to edit current line

Tags: zsh

`bindkey` builtin of zsh seems to be a good start. But I don't know how to write a function that binds to a key, say `Ctr+/`, to look for a pattern and delete the current line to the end. The pattern can be a default one or a string provided at the time user invokes the function.

An example use case:

When I type this command, and append with a comment:

```
echo Hello World # Try echo
```

After that, I scroll back the history and want to reuse the command, I want to quickly delete from `#` to the end and start typing new command from there.

Another use:

When I scroll up the line, I want to call the function, let's name it `deleteFrom`, it will prompt for input, with default is `#`. I can type `World`. It then delete the line from "World" to the end, at place the cursor there so I can start typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to [extend Zle](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html) (Z-shell Line Editor) by adding your own widget to browse history and then edit picked up line (if I understand question correctly).

Here is super simple widget bound to 'C' that will remove any characters after # on current command line (this will also work for lines fetched from history):

```sh
my-zle-widget () {
  BUFFER="${BUFFER%%#*}"
  zle .end-of-line
}

zle -N my-zle-widget

bindkey C my-zle-widget
```

You don't need to implement everything from scratch and can call out to existing zle widgets for bits of work that's already implemented (see `zle .end-of-line` in my example). You can use code of those in [zsh repo](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/tree/master/Functions/Zle) as reference (note that those are autoloaded and don't need to be wrapped in a function - they are only function bodies).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will check more about Zle. Regarding your example, it will be better if it allows editing the commanline, and do not submit. It should wait until I hit Enter.

Comment: Good point. Updated my answer to actually work with command line `$BUFFER`.